# How to set header and parameter for route.get in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to set header and parameter for route.get in node js?
I want to set header value and parameter to API data call URL.

```
router.get("/getdata", async (req, res) => {
  res.header({
    'key': '123456'
  });
  await fetch(`https://example.com/api?param=${data}`)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => res.json({ msg: data }))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

my question is how to set header and parameter data in router.get in node js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear and you should add more details to it and ask the specific things which might be causing an issue.

Headers are set on the response which can be done directly on res object like this:

```
res.set({
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
  'Content-Length': '123',
  'ETag': '12345'
})
```

Check [this](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) for more details.

If you need to set headers on fetch API call, You can do that directly on fetch as below:

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}
```

If you want to read params in the req object:

```
router.get("/getdata", async (req, res) => {
  const query = req.query // its an object containing all the params 
  await fetch(`https://example.com/api?param=${data}`)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => res.json({ msg: data }))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for Express around routing. It explains on how to e.g. use `req.query` to access the `param` in that fetch URL.

Comment: it would have been better framed as a comment for op's question.